# Access 2010 VBA API TWIPS/PIXEL

Tags: api, vba, ms-access, pointers

a question regarding API calls and the TWIPS/pixel problem working for 32- and 64-bit systems.
I want a popup-form to show up at the mouse pointer's position. My solution kind of works (at least without crashing) but doesn't seem to calculate the correct position.

```
'API Calls
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiGetWindowRect Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowRect" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpRect As RECT_Type) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiGetDC Lib "user32" Alias "GetDC" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiGetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetDeviceCaps" (ByVal hDC As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiReleaseDC Lib "user32" Alias "ReleaseDC" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hDC As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Const TWIPSPERINCH = 1440
Private Const WU_LOGPIXELSX = 88
Private Const WU_LOGPIXELSY = 90

Private Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

Type RECT_Type
    left As Long
    top As Long
    right As Long
    bottom As Long
 End Type

Public Function GetXCursorPos() As Long
    Dim pt As POINTAPI
    GetCursorPos pt
    GetXCursorPos = CLng(pt.X)
End Function

Public Function GetYCursorPos() As Long
    Dim pt As POINTAPI
    GetCursorPos pt
    GetYCursorPos = pt.Y
End Function

Public Function ConvertPIXELSToTWIPS(lPixel As Long, _
                                 lDirection As Long) As Long

    Dim hDC As LongPtr
    Dim hWnd As Long
    Dim RetVal As LongPtr
    Dim PIXELSPERINCH

    hDC = apiGetDC(0)

    ' Horizontal
    If (lDirection = 0) Then
        PIXELSPERINCH = apiGetDeviceCaps(hDC, WU_LOGPIXELSX)
    ' Vertical
    Else
        PIXELSPERINCH = apiGetDeviceCaps(hDC, WU_LOGPIXELSY)
    End If

    RetVal = apiReleaseDC(0, hDC)

    ConvertPIXELSToTWIPS = (lPixel / PIXELSPERINCH) * TWIPSPERINCH

End Function

Function ConvertTwipsToPixels(lTwips As Long, _
                          lDirection As Long) As Long

    Dim lDC As LongPtr
    Dim lPixelsPerInch As LongPtr

    lDC = apiGetDC(0)

    ' Horizontal
    If (lDirection = 0) Then
        lPixelsPerInch = apiGetDeviceCaps(lDC, WU_LOGPIXELSX)
    ' Vertical
    Else
        lPixelsPerInch = apiGetDeviceCaps(lDC, WU_LOGPIXELSY)
    End If

    lDC = apiReleaseDC(0, lDC)

    ConvertTwipsToPixels = (lTwips / TWIPSPERINCH) * lPixelsPerInch

End Function
```

The form itself would be opened like this

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim lWidthPixel As Long
    Dim lHeightPixel As Long

    Dim lWidthTwips As Long
    Dim lHeightTwips As Long

    lWidthPixel = modAPI.GetXCursorPos
    lHeightPixel = modAPI.GetYCursorPos

    lWidthTwips = ConvertPIXELSToTWIPS(lWidthPixel, 0)
    lHeightTwips = ConvertPIXELSToTWIPS(lHeightPixel, 1)
    Me.Move left:=lWidthTwips, top:=lHeightTwips
 End Sub
```

I must confess that my programming skill have to surrender when it comes to API programming, especially with having to juggle with long and longptr. The code above is gathered from different sources. Any help is greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Jon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position isn't calculated correctly because you are not taking into account the fact `GetCursorPos` returns screen coordinates and `Form.Move` assumes coordinates relative to the main Access window, or more exactly, a custom (not Windows-defined) client area of that window. Separately, your code is also a bit confused about `LongPtr`:

- The Windows API is full of pointers (a pointer being a simple reference to a thing not the thing itself) and 'handles' (which are just opaque pointers). When targeting Win32, pointer values are 32 bits wide; when compiling for Win64, 64 bits wide. Traditionally VBA did not have a pointer type, which forced people to hardcode pointers and handles to `Long` values, i.e. 32 bit integers. However, Office 2010 finally introduced `LongPtr` (why not `Pointer` I don't know!), which should be used for declaring pointers and handles going forward since it maps to a 64 bit `LongLong` in a 64 bit version of Office.
- Unfortunately typedefs/type aliases were *not* added though, so even in the latest versions of VBA you can't just declare the various API types and have (say) a `HDC` parameter shown as typed to `HDC` like you would in C, C++ or Delphi.
- Another thing to keep in mind is that not every API type that is 32 bits wide when targeting Win32 becomes 64 bits wide when targeting Win64. In particular, the `BOOL` type remains 32 bits long, along with the C/C++ `int`.
- Not important because you included it anyway, but the `PtrSafe` attribute in a `Declare` statement is just a marker to tell Office that you know what you are doing and can confirm the `Declare` statement is 64 bit compatible.

Personally I'd clean your API declarations up like the following - your (inconsistent) renaming of identifiers is a bit pointless, occasionally you wrongly use `LongPtr` for values that aren't pointers or handles, and occasionally you wrongly use `Long` when `LongPtr` should be used:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" ( _
  ByRef lpPoint As POINT) As Long ' returns a BOOL

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Long ' returns a BOOL

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr ' returns a HDC - Handle to a Device Context

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" ( _
  ByVal hDC As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long ' returns a C/C++ int

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal hDC As LongPtr) As Long ' also returns an int

Private Const LOGPIXELSX = 88 ' sticking to the original names is less confusing IMO
Private Const LOGPIXELSY = 90 ' ditto

Private Const TwipsPerInch = 1440

Type POINT
  X As Long
  Y As Long
End Type

Type RECT
  Left As Long
  Top As Long
  Right As Long
  Bottom As Long
End Type
```

Now we get to the code proper; I'd suggest something like this:

```
Function PixelsToTwips(ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As POINT
  Dim ScreenDC As LongPtr
  ScreenDC = GetDC(0)
  PixelsToTwips.X = X / GetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC, LOGPIXELSX) * TwipsPerInch
  PixelsToTwips.Y = Y / GetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC, LOGPIXELSY) * TwipsPerInch
  ReleaseDC 0, ScreenDC
End Function

Function TwipsToPixels(ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As POINT
  Dim ScreenDC As LongPtr
  ScreenDC = GetDC(0)
  TwipsToPixels.X = X / TwipsPerInch * GetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC, LOGPIXELSX)
  TwipsToPixels.Y = Y / TwipsPerInch * GetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC, LOGPIXELSY)
  ReleaseDC 0, ScreenDC
End Function

Sub MoveFormToScreenPixelPos(Form As Access.Form, PixelX As Long, PixelY As Long)
  Dim FormWR As RECT, AccessWR As RECT, Offset As POINT, NewPos As POINT
  ' firstly need to calculate what the coords passed to Move are relative to
  GetWindowRect Application.hWndAccessApp, AccessWR
  GetWindowRect Form.hWnd, FormWR
  Offset = PixelsToTwips(FormWR.Left - AccessWR.Left, FormWR.Top - AccessWR.Top)
  Offset.X = Offset.X - Form.WindowLeft
  Offset.Y = Offset.Y - Form.WindowTop
  ' next convert our desired position to twips and set it
  NewPos = PixelsToTwips(PixelX - AccessWR.Left, PixelY - AccessWR.Top)
  Form.Move NewPos.X - Offset.X, NewPos.Y - Offset.Y
End Sub

Sub MoveFormToCursorPos(Form As Access.Form)
  Dim Pos As POINT
  GetCursorPos Pos
  MoveFormToScreenPixelPos Form, Pos.X, Pos.Y
End Sub
```

The tricky thing is figuring out what exactly the coords passed to `Move` are supposed to be relative to - it's not just the Access window's 'client area' from the API's point of view, so we have to figure things out by looking at the form's current position in Access' wacky-backy terms and comparing it with its position at the API level. From this we get an offset which we use when applying the new position.

To use, the Load event handler just needs to do this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  MoveFormToCursorPos Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This looks like quite a lot of work. I'll give it a shot tomorrow and let you know.